# Design pattern for threadpooling

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, design-patterns, threadpool

I currently have an application that has a large number of threads and this makes the application very large.  Each thread is long-running, basically an infinite loop of polling for new emails then handling them.  Each thread holds on to one SSL connection, which is why threading works well for the application.

I want to use thread pooling.  The simplest approach is to just fix the number of threads then add say 10 users per thread but even at that point it does not seem to be balancing the work as uniformly as 1 user / thread as each loop is fairly long to process.  Plus this isn't actually a thread pool.

My question is - what is the proper design pattern here (as it's certainly more intelligent than what I wrote above), and is there a C++ library that handles this well?  It would also be helpful to point me to a Java utility as in my experience it's pretty easy to work out a design pattern from a Java utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One user/thread is probably a good starting point.  Anything that blocks or can be blocked needs to run in its own thread to avoid holding up or being held up by other executing code.  If the actual processing of an e-mail is going to run straight through, it can be placed in a "runnable", to use the Java term, and submitted to a thread pool.  The Java term would be [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), and it can't be that hard to write a simple one yourself.  You'd want one thread for each likely CPU core to get the most work from your computer.

If the work per e-mail is not that great, it might be simpler and faster to skip the thread pool and just do the work on the reader thread.  You've paid the cost to run it, you may as well get all the work out of it you can.

At the other extreme, if processing an e-mail involves blocking or getting blocked, you may want to fire up a new thread for each e-mail.  You can end up with a *lot* of threads, but it will get the maximum amount of work out of your computer.  You don't want to be falling behind on your e-mails with your CPU usage at only 5%.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a BlockingDeque in between with a thread pooled consumer on the back end.  That decouples the email producers from the consumers and allows you to pool up the consumers on the back end.  Have a look at this:

[Producer Consumer Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ProducerandconsumerbasedonBlockingQueue.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous patterns that could solve the problem, but the key point in making the decision is understanding the pattern's consequences.  The [ACE website](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html) has some papers for some concurrency patterns that may be suitable, such as [Active Object](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf), [Proactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/proactor.pdf), and [Reactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf).  The examples are C++, but there are diagrams and descriptions that will be helpful if you pursue your own implementation.

The [proactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/proactor.pdf) may provide an elegant solution or serve as the foundation for another pattern.  For C++ implementations, I would recommend the [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library:

- Fairly well documented and examples.
- SSL support.
- The [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3) example shows how to use `boost::asio` with a thread pool.

If you do not want a dependency on `boost`, then the `asio` library is also packaged separately [here](http://think-async.com/).  For more patterns and information, consider [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471606952) book.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your statement "does not seem to be balancing the work as uniformly as 1 user / thread as each loop is fairly long to process".

In any case, the [Active Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) pattern could be an elegant one in your case. This is a combination of 6 other patterns. In effect, this achieves a thread pool with nicely abstracted entities.

Comment: Active Object may be wasting threads in a strategy of one thread per one Active Object. you should have M threads in a pool per N objects , but then you will reach synchronization issues that I'm not sure the writer of the  question would like to experience.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [commons ThreadPool](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/threadpool/). Altough Java - it's open source, you can look at the code and easily port to C++